# Scope visibility of struct members while passing as a argument?

Tags: go

While calling json.Decoder.Decode by passing a struct, for instance

```
type _Sample struct {
    first string // this will not be filled because it starts with lower case letter
    Second string // it is OK. 
}

...
var sample _Sample
err := decoder.Decode(&sample)
```

According to the Language Specification that writes:

> Exported identifiers ¶
>
> An identifier may be exported to permit access to it from another package. An identifier is exported if both:
>
> - the first character of the identifier's name is a Unicode upper case letter (Unicode class "Lu"); and
> - the identifier is declared in the package block or it is a field name or method name.
>
> All other identifiers are not exported.

The question is the struct `_Sample` is not exported, why it is visible by the package `json`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Access permission* is checked when

1. You're creating/declaring a variable. The compiler will check the visibility of *the name of the type identifier*.
2. Using [`reflect`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) package to modify a variable.
3. Calling a constant, global variable, or a function. The visibility of constant/variable/function name will be checked.

Once the variable is created/defined, and when you pass this variable as a function/method argument, the copy (If it is a value, the value is being copied. If it is a pointer, the address is being copied) will be passed to the function/method, and **always accessible** from the function body through the argument name and type. In `encoding/json` package, the [`Decoder.Decode`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Decoder.Decode) method is defined as,

```
func (dec *Decoder) Decode(v interface{}) error
```

thus, anything you passed to the `Decoder.Decode` method, is always accessible from inside the method body through argument `v`. Note that the type of `v` is `interface{}` not `_Sample` struct. The visibility is checked when you defined the variable as

```
var sample _Sample
```

which was *OK* since it is done from within the same package. Even an anonymous struct (i.e. no type name identifier is defined for the struct)

```
aSample := struct {
    first  string // this will not be filled because it starts with lower case letter
    Second string // it is OK.
}{}

//...
err := decoder.Decode(&aSample)
```

will works. Next, when the `decoder` fills the struct (through reflection), the visibility of struct members will be checked, and `_Sample.first` is not visible from inside the `json` package.